# Searching for NetBIOS name HTML input pattern

Tags: regex, input, netbios

I want to add a pattern to one of my input tags, which checks, if the given input by the user is a correct NetBIOS name.

NetBIOS names can have a maximum amount of 15 characters. It can contains numbers and JUST upper case letters...

I've tried to solve this problem with the following code, but it does not work:

```
    pattern="/([A-Z0-9]{1,15})/"
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a string to `pattern`; you want to use a regex literal:

```
if(/^[A-Z0-9]{1,15)$/.test(string)) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: If the user clicks on the button "submit", the next page will open. I want, that the page do not change and that a hint will be displayed. That's the reason, why I want to use 'pattern=""'...

Comment: That's not what you asked in your question... please edit the question or make a new one.